# Spring batch itemwriter interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, itemwriter

The write method of Itemwriter has been changed in the spring version 5.

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends List<DataDTO>> items) throws Exception{
    for(List<DataDTO> sublist:items){
        writer.write(sublist);
}
```

The above writer is FlatFileItemWriter.

I changed to the following

```
@Override
public void write(Chunk<? extends List<DataDTO>> items) throws Exception{
    for(List<DataDTO> sublist:items){
        writer.write((Chunk<? extends DataDTO>)sublist);
    }
}
```

Is this correct way of replacing/fix? need some help.

Im expecting the correct fix.

Comment: Neither of your code snippet are syntactically valid. Can you please fix your question?

Comment: @Oliver Thanks for letting me know,Can u check now please?